# Singularities of $\frac{z^2-\pi^2}{\sin(z)}$ and $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analytic-functions, singularity

> Determine all singularities and their types of this functions:
>   $$f(z)=\frac{z^2-\pi^2}{\sin(z)} \qquad\text{and}\qquad g(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}$$

---

For the **first one** I thought this:
Obviously there is a singularity at $z_0=0$. To determine the typ I did this:
$$\begin{align*}
f(z)=\frac{z^2-\pi^2}{\sin(z)}&=(z^2-\pi^2)\left(-\frac{1}{z}+\frac{3!}{z^3}±\dots\right)\\
&= \left(z-\frac{\pi^2}{z}\right)+\left(\frac{3!}{z}-\frac{3!\pi^2}{z^3}\right)±\dots\end{align*}$$

Unfortunately I don't how to get further. I suppose that $z_0$ is a pole.

---

For the **second one** I have no idea to evaluate the typ. Sure I know that the singularity is at $z_1=0$ and I put in the series expansion of $e^z$, but this didn't help me.

---

Any hints? Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Singularities of

$\frac{z^2-\pi^2}{\sin(z)}$  are given by $z=k\pi $ with $ k\in \mathbb Z$ which are poles except $z=\pm \pi. $ where the singularity is apparent(fake singularity or removable singularity). Indeed $\sin z =0 
$ iff $z=\pi k$. But 
$$\lim_{z\to \pm \pi} \frac{z^2-\pi^2}{\sin z } =-\lim_{z\to \pm \pi} \frac{(z-\pi)(z+\pi)}{\sin( z\mp\pi )} = \mp 2\pi.$$

and the same for

$\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ are given by $z=2i\pi k $ with $ k\in \mathbb Z$ which are poles except $z=0. $ where the singularity is apparent(fake singularity or removable singularity). $e^z=1
$ iff $z=2i\pi k$. but 
$$\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z}{e^z -1 } =1$$

Comment: We have $\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z}{e^z -1 } =1$ !

Comment: thanks I fixed it now

Comment: @GuyFsone How do you get the limit of the second one?

Comment: you can use the hospital rule or taylor expansion

Answer (score 0):

For $\frac{z}{e^z - 1}$, remember that 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{az + bz^2 + \ldots} 
&= \frac{1}{a} \cdot \frac{1}{z + (b/a)z^2 + \ldots} \\
&= \frac{1}{az} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + (b/a)z + \ldots} \\
&= \frac{1}{az} \left( 1 - (b/a)z + \ldots \right)\\
\end{align}
at least when the series in the denominator (after the initial "1") converges to something whose modulus is less than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: 1.  We have $\lim_{z \to 0} z f(z)=- \pi^2.$

Can you now deduce that $0$ is a simple pole of $f$ ?

2. We have $\lim_{z \to 0}g(z)=1$.

Can you now deduce that $0$ is a removable singularity of $g$ ?

Comment: Why and how we take $zf(z)$?